# CSS breadcrumb step indicator resize issue

Tags: css, breadcrumbs

I have a breadcrumb at the top of my shopping site. It shows how many steps there are and how far along they are in the process of making a purchase. Not meant to be click able.

The problem I have is when viewing from a phone or smaller window, it gets squeezed and appears over two lines instead of one line.

Is there a way to have the whole thing appear in a line, preferably 100% of the screen width, and automatically resized to fit in 100% of smaller screen width?

Currently it has a fixed width based on how many steps there are. I am trying to make it automatically resized to bigger, equal sized steps on bigger screens, and made smaller but still inline on smaller screens like phones and tablets.

```css
    .step-indicator {
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      line-height: 30px;
    }
    
    .step {
      display: inline;
      float: left;
      font-weight: normal;
      background: #858585;
      padding-right: 10px;
      height: 30px;
      line-height: 32px;
      margin-right: 33px;
      position: relative;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #fff;
      cursor: default;
    }
    .step:before {
      content: "";
      display: block;
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: -30px;
      border: 15px solid transparent;
      border-color: #858585;
      border-left-color: transparent;
    }
    .step:after {
      content: "";
      display: block;
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: -30px;
      border: 15px solid transparent;
      border-left-color: #858585;
    }
    .step:first-of-type {
      border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
      padding-left: 15px;
    }
    .step:first-of-type:before {
      display: none;
    }
    .step:last-of-type {
      border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
      margin-right: 25px;
      padding-right: 15px;
    }
    .step:last-of-type:after {
      display: none;
    }
    .step.completed {
      background: #CC2262;
      color: #fff;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    .step.completed:before {
      border-color: #CC2262;
      border-left-color: transparent;
    }
    .step.completed:after {
      border-left-color: #CC2262;
    }
    .step.completed:hover {
      background: #CC2262;
      border-color: #CC2262;
      color: #fff;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    .step.completed:hover:before {
      border-color: #CC2262;
      border-left-color: transparent;
    }
    .step.completed:hover:after {
      border-left-color: #CC2262;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="step-indicator">
      <a class="step completed">Step 1</a>
      <a class="step completed">Step 2</a>
      <a class="step completed">Step 3</a>
      <a class="step">Step 4</a>
      <a class="step">Step 5</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: No, you can’t have that all “automatically” with CSS alone. On larger screen this is mainly an element alignment/spacing issue - but on small screens, you will have to reduce the font size at some point, otherwise it simply _can’t_ fit on one line. But even with viewport relative units, you would still need to know roughly how many characters there are going to be upfront.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `display:flex;` to stretch out the content and a media query to change the font size when the page gets below a certain width. Unfortunately, there isn't a way, using only CSS, to make font work out its own sizing to fit.

```css
.step-indicator {
  display: flex;
}

.step:first-of-type::before,
.step:last-of-type::after {
  display: none;
}

.step {
  flex: 1;
  background: #858585;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin-right: 33px;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: default;
}

.step::after,
.step::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.step::before {
  left: -30px;
  border: 15px solid transparent;
  border-color: #858585 #858585 #858585 transparent;
}

.step::after {
  right: -30px;
  border: 15px solid transparent;
  border-left-color: #858585;
}

.step:first-of-type {
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.step:last-of-type {
  border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.step.completed {
  background: #CC2262;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.step.completed::before {
  border-color: #CC2262 #CC2262 #CC2262 transparent;
}

.step.completed::after {
  border-left-color: #CC2262;
}
```

```html
<div class="step-indicator">
  <a class="step completed">Step 1</a>
  <a class="step completed">Step 2</a>
  <a class="step completed">Step 3</a>
  <a class="step">Step 4</a>
  <a class="step">Step 5</a>
</div>
```

In my example, I stripped out some of the CSS that wasn't doing anything and added the flex bits.

For some further reading, I'd suggest looking at [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) and [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

I hope this is helpful

Comment: This worked. But still not working on mobile. Any way to break it into 2 lines if the window is too small? Currently its one line, and the rest disappears into the edge of the screen, previously it was 2 lines, but messed up.